# React: Reset class when click on others elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created an hamburger menu that change the class name when a button is click it. This works

```
const Hamburger = ()=> {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    function showIt() {
        setShow(!show);
    }
    return (
        <HamburgerIcon className={show ? 'menu-open' : ' menu-close '} onClick={showIt}>
            <span></span>
        </HamburgerIcon>
    )
}
export default Hamburger;
```

Default state for the hamburger is ".menu-close" if you click toggle to ".menu-open". But when I click in a link inside the menu, the menu remain open.

What I want to achieve is to change the class also if a link in the menu is click it.

Any suggestion on what I should do here?

Thank you!!

Comment: Where is the menu rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `showIt` function to the link inside the menu

Code:

```js
const Hamburger = ()=> {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    function showIt() {
        setShow(!show);
    }
    return (
        <HamburgerIcon className={show ? 'menu-open' : ' menu-close '} onClick={showIt}>
          <a href="/some/path" onClick={showIt}>
          Example
          </a>
        </HamburgerIcon>
    )
}
export default Hamburger;
```

Comment: I thought about that too but my links are in another component <Link to="/about">About</Link>

Comment: @Rola then pass a function prop to the component

Answer (score 1):

You can lift the state up to the parent component.

In the example below, I've lifted the state up to the lowest common ancestor component of `Menu` and `Hamburger` components. And then passed down the state via props.

```js
function Hamburger({ isOpen, onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Menu {isOpen ? "↓" : "→"}</button>;
}

function Menu({ isOpen, menuItems, onClick }) {
  if (!isOpen) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <ul>
      {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button onClick={onClick}>{item}</button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <nav>
      <Hamburger isOpen={isOpen} onClick={handleClick} />
      <Menu
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClick={handleClick}
        menuItems={["Home", "About", "Contact"]}
      />
    </nav>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```